# Changing the user that nginx worker processes run under (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04, usergroups

I have a manual install of nginx on Ubuntu 12.04. When I ran `./configure` I used the following options:

```
./configure --user=www-data --group=www-data --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module
```

Now the nginx worker processes run under the www-data user in the www-data group. However, I wish to change this to a different user (called nginx in my case).

Is this possible to do after running `make` and `make install` already?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As long as your new user (*nginx* in your case) has the proper rights, everything should work.

You have to change your *user* setting in *nginx.conf*

```
...
user nginx;
...
```

and restart/reload your server. [Link to docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#user).

Comment: On nginx 1.8 and later you must also specify the group, for example "user nginx staff;"

Comment: bear in mind that this directive should be in the "main" context, that is, outside any other directive.

Answer (score 6):

If you use PHP5-FPM and get a 502 error after restart nginx, take a look on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock (Debian) :

root@ns353941:/var/run# chown nginx:www php5-fpm.sock

In my case :

nginx = new nginx user

www = group for web

nginx user belong to www, obviously.